# How to display JSON data in a DataGridView in WinForms?

Tags: c#, json, winforms, datagridview, deserialization

This is the JSON data that I have:

```
{"testId":1,"testName":"HTML","minScore":20,"score":40,"date":"12-2-2014","status":"PASSED"},
{"testId":1,"testName":"JAVA","minScore":20,"score":10,"date":"12-2-2014","status":"FAILED"}
```

How can I show it in a DataGridView?

Answer (score 35):

So this is pretty straight forward:

1. Declare a class to deserialize into.
2. Grab the Json.NET NuGet Package.
3. Deserialize the string.
4. Bind the `DataGridView`.

## Declare a class to deserialize into

```
public class JsonResult
{
    public int testId { get; set; }
    public string testName { get; set; }
    public int minScore { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

## Grab the Json.NET NuGet Package

Pull the `Json.NET` NuGet Package in from here http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/6.0.3.

## Deserialize the string

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonResult>>(input);
```

## Bind the `DataGridView`

```
dataGridView.DataSource = result;
```

**NOTE:** this is the most primitive way of binding to the grid. There are many more options that you can leverage. One that comes to mind is, turning off `AutoGenerateColumns` and defining your own columns; designer-driven work so it wouldn't affect the code I've provided.

Comment: It doesn't work with me. The datasource is correctly structured (each field from the json gets to one column) but rows are equals to nothing.

Comment: @mike I have the same problem as the opener. But 1st <List<JsonResult>> makes an exception. I found only a way to make a class JsonResultList with an Array of JsonResult (I use the sample data from the opener). So then conversion will work but No data is shown in the grid. Are there steps missing?

Comment: I had to use a `BindingSource` object, then result as it's source:  `bindingSource.DataSource = result`. Finally set `dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource`. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 7):

There's a simpler way to do this. You don't need to create a new class. Simply do:

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, (typeof(DataTable)));
dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```

No need for a custom class. You'll still need Newtonsoft though.

Comment: This answer does work perfectly while Mike Perrenoud answer doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
> 2. using System.Net;

```
void get_response()
{
     WebClient wp = new WebClient();
     string url="your json url";
     var response=wp.DownloadString(url)
     get_data(response)
}


void get_data(string response)
{
    datagridview.Rows.clear();`enter code here`
    JArray fetch= JArray.Parse(response);
    if(fetch.Count()>0)
    {
        for(int i=0;datagridview.Rows.Count>i;i++)
        {
            int n=datagridview.Rows.Add();
            datagridview.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value=fetch[i]["Json 
            ObjectName1"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```