# Wrong Values with Datagrid using WCF

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, datagrid

I have already a WCF restful apps working and I try to get the json to the Winforms but it give me wrong values and sometimes blocked
this my code for button of Winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
        string serviceURL = string.Format("http://localhost:55495/EventService.svc/GetAllEvents/");
        byte[] data = proxy.DownloadData(serviceURL);
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
        DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(EventDataContract));
        EventDataContract Eventdatacontract = obj.ReadObject(stream) as EventDataContract;

        string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy";
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Event ID";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Text";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Start Date";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "End Date";


        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string[] row = new string[] { Eventdatacontract.EventID.ToString(), Eventdatacontract.Text, Eventdatacontract.Start_Date.ToString(format), Eventdatacontract.End_Date.ToString(format) };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }


    }
```

for the data it shows like this
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to fill the DataGridView with the data returned by your WCF? Then that loop seems quite wrong.

Comment: yes, so any idea about solution

Comment: It is not clear what the WCF returns. It is a collection of _Eventdatacontract_ or it is just one element? And then what are these wrong values that you get back from WCF?

Comment: its return a int, string, datetime, datetime. and it return collection of elements, for the wrong value u can see the pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte[] data = proxy.DownloadData(serviceURL);
```

is responsible for the blocking UI. You should consider making this call asynchronously, i.e.:

```
byte[] data = await Task.Run(() => proxy.DownloadData(serviceURL));
```

**NOTE**: When using the await keyword within a method you have to change the method signature.

In your case:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

---

**UPDATE**

As you found a working solution, you could also add async functions here to ensure a non blocking UI:

**Note:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_NamingConvention

> By convention, you append "Async" to the names of methods that have an Async or async modifier.

```
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
...
private async Task<JArray> GetRESTDataAsync(string uri)
{
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
    var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
    string s = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s));
}
```

You could also use `return await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<JArray>(s);` but Json.NET has marked it as obsolete and recommend using `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.

Comment: For the other issue, could you try to convert the byte array into a readable JSON string and post it here? Also you could use Json.NET for converting JSON etc. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: but the json work with WCF, when I set the link, it shows all the values

Comment: What do you mean by set the link? And where do you see all the values? However, your way of filling the dataGridView is a bit confusing, as you iterate through your rows but you add the first row within that loop? You should consider setting the 'datasource' property of the dataGridView. Therefore, you could set it to a DataTable for example.

Comment: A short example of doing similar things (Json.NET) can you find here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763446/how-to-display-the-json-data-in-datagridview-in-c-sharp-windows-application-from

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution for me, just install **Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json** and add it to reference

```
public void  button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = GetRESTData("http://localhost:55495/EventService.svc/GetAllEvents");
        }
        catch (WebException webex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Es gab so ein Schlamassel! ({0})", webex.Message);
        }
    }

    private JArray GetRESTData(string uri)
    {
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
    }
```